# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'popupTheme' in package "com.example..."

Tags: android, compiler-errors, attributes, resources, identifier

There are a lot of questions similar to this, but I didn't get specific to my code. None of them are working for this.

I am trying to add a toolbar a shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

But this doesn't work for me as it shows me the error

`No resource identifier found for attribute 'popupTheme' in package "com.example...`

My code goes like this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also added the `appcompat` and `cardview` library but still I get the same error.

Does any one know the answer? Please reply.

Comment: Hi Vidhi, it's not possible to debug this unless you share your java code as well. Along with it if you can share logcat stack trace then it will be even better. Probably you are messing some layout inflation in java code.

Comment: Although in your xml you can try removing both theme attributes. That might give you some result without error.

Answer (score 0):

define below style in style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

change

```
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

to

```
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove app from app:style 
And in style `<style name="Theme ovelrlay... Your style name" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
</style>`
It should work fine
Tick the answer correct thanks